# OpenCV createTrackbar

Tags: c++, opencv

I am attempting to create a Track bar on my OpenCV application using createTrackbar function provided by OpenCV.

I want to add three trackbars actually one that will shuffle through range of colours, 2nd one that shuffles through Canny filter values and 3rd that shuffles through medianBlur values.

I am struggling with adding pointer to an integer variable, whose value will reflect the position of the slider.

So here is my inRange & Canny filter & medianNlur functions:

```
    Mat range_out;
        inRange(blur_out, Scalar(100, 100, 100), Scalar(120, 255, 255), range_out); 

    Mat mBlur;
        medianBlur(erode,mBlur,7);

        Mat canny_out;
        Canny(mBlur, canny_out, 125,350);


        createTrackbar("Colour values: ", window_Output, &range_out, 255);
createTrackbar("Colour values: ", window_Output, &mBlur, 7);
createTrackbar("Colour values: ", window_Output, &canny_out, 350);
```

From what i read the the variables have to be integer(i.e. range_out is Matrix Mat not int)

Could someone direct me to a decent tutorial where i could find my answer that I am looking for or explain how to do it.

Comment: You cannot point to a `Mat` from `createTrackbar` prior to http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html, this has to be a `int`.

Comment: Yes i know is stated that but the a question remains how do i do it then.....?

Comment: I have added a answer, but i would also like to refer to following example http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/trackbar/trackbar.html

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the callback function in following fashion, which makes the code less cumbersome.

```
const int median_blur_max = 5;
int median_blur;
Mat img;
Mat src, dst;

void callBackFunction( int, void* ) {
    medianBlur(src,dst,median_blur);
    imshow("Controls", img );
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
     namedWindow("Controls", 1);
     createTrackbar("Median blur", "Controls", &median_blur, median_blur_max, callBackFunction );

     callBackFunction(median_blur, 3);

     waitKey(0);
     return 0;
}
```

The example is not complete, but gives a good overview of the elements and useage of the callBackFunction.

It seems unclear to me if you wish to change `Mat` in your functions or not, but if thats the case you can simply add a `switch-case`or `if-sentence` in the `callBackFunction` that changes the Mat for a given function call.